# Processing JS svg load - Google Appengine

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-app-engine, svg, processing

i have a problem. I want to use my Processing code on the Google appengine cloud. I load the svg file asynchronously visa @psj preload tag and i have the map1.svg in the same directory as the .pde file, so I just want to display a PShape but it doesn't show up. I have the following processing code:

EDITED SEE BELOW !

I have all the files (.pde, processing lib, geoloc.js) and the map1.svg in the same folder ../static/processing/ .

Has anybody managed to get a processing file on the app engine, where the script uses loadImage() or loadShape() ? By the way the geoloc.js library is working and the processing code also works if I don't use the loadShape function, so i suspect that the path to map1.svg isn't correct ?

EDIT !!!!!!!!!

Ok so now i have stripped the files as much as possible and the map is still not shown on the appengine, the .html works if i open it in my desktop, so I still supspect that it has something to do with the loading of the map1.svg file in the processing code. I must point out that the processing .pde source is found it's just the map that is not shown !

Here is my crunched processing code:

EDITED AGAIN ! IT'S WORKING NOW...THE PATH SHOULD BE MORE SPECIFIC - relative !

```
/* @pjs preload="../static/processing/map1.svg"; */

PShape worldMap;

void setup ()
{
    size(500, 500);
    worldMap = loadShape("../static/processing/map1.svg");
}

void draw ()
{
    shape(worldMap, 0, 0, 500, 500);

}
```

And the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>hiToYouToo : Built with Processing and Processing.js</title>
    <meta name="Generator" content="Processing" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript">alert("Your browser does not support the canvas tag.");</script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="../static/processing/processing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // convenience function to get the id attribute of generated sketch html element
    function getProcessingSketchId () { return 'hiToYouToo'; }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div>
            <canvas id="hiToYouToo" data-processing-sources="../static/processing/hiToYouToo.pde"
                    width="500" height="500">
                <p>Your browser does not support the canvas tag.</p>
                <!-- Note: you can put any alternative content here. -->
            </canvas>
            <noscript>
                <p>JavaScript is required to view the contents of this page.</p>
            </noscript>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: a note on your HTML: if you say `<!doctype html>` you're declaring you're using HTML5, but your HTML doesn't follow HTML5 convention. the meta tag you want in HTML5 is `<meta charset="utf-8">`, and they don't use XML selfclosing syntax. Scripts don't need a type if they're javascript, a noscript element doesn't even make sense anymore (the only way you don't have JS is if you've intentionally turned it off. No browser 'doesn't support javascript', and that's been the case for years now).

Comment: so that aside: reduce your testcase. Have the @pjs preload, and just a setup() and draw() that only load your .svg file with loadShape, and then draw it using shape(...), once. Does that work? If not, let's examine that code instead of the more complex code you've added your post. Most of that code is not relevant to the problem you're asking about.

Comment: Ok i edited the code now...stripped down. It's really strange cause everything else works, i mean besides the loading of the shape, so i think that processing loadShape isn't searching it's file in the correct place. How to tell where to search ? Hmmm I answered the question myself lol. I had to change the path of loading the maps in .pde also ! See the edited code again...

Comment: what does your browser's dev tools say? If it fails to grab it, it'll show up as a 404 in the console and the network tab.

Comment: That's not completely true, my console outputs the the error if the .pde is not found then it reports the 404 ajax request, but if the .svg is not found then no error is shown. But as I stated before i have solved the problem, check my edited code in .pde file, the path to the .svg is now referencing the whole path to it.

Comment: ah. I did not notice that the first time. yes, whatever you preload needs to use the same path as the preload command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so just to answer myself formally, so anyone looking for this would quickly find the answer.

Here is the processing code on app engine:

```
/* @pjs preload="../static/processing/map1.svg"; */

PShape worldMap;

void setup ()
{
    size(500, 500);
    worldMap = loadShape("../static/processing/map1.svg");
}

void draw ()
{
    shape(worldMap, 0, 0, 500, 500);

}
```

And the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>hiToYouToo : Built with Processing and Processing.js</title>
    <meta name="Generator" content="Processing" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript">alert("Your browser does not support the canvas tag.");</script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="../static/processing/processing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // convenience function to get the id attribute of generated sketch html element
    function getProcessingSketchId () { return 'hiToYouToo'; }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div>
            <canvas id="hiToYouToo" data-processing-sources="../static/processing/hiToYouToo.pde"
                    width="500" height="500">
                <p>Your browser does not support the canvas tag.</p>
                <!-- Note: you can put any alternative content here. -->
            </canvas>
            <noscript>
                <p>JavaScript is required to view the contents of this page.</p>
            </noscript>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```